# Unable to add files due to git due to a checkout issue

Tags: git, maven, github

I am unable to add any files to git when I give command '`git add .`' in a Git bash session.
It shows error:

```
'EG' does not have a commit checked out. 
 fatal : adding files failed.
```

I am unable to do any operation in Git now.

I tried all `git checkout` commands, deleted branches.
I even deleted git bash from my system.

Tried to search commits in Git GUI but there too I found nothing.
Did all this but to no success. Please help me.

Attaching the image of steps I followed and error that I am getting

[image: Git error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi so let me tell you the basic steps on how to use git to push something. Just check if you are following all these.

If you have a new project and it does not have git initialized then do: -

```
git init
```

then whenever you do some changes in the project folder and save it just go back to git and do:-

```
git status
```

if it shows some file names in red that means those files have been changed and now you need to stage the changes you want to commit.

So if you want to stage a single file then copy that file path shown in the bash window and do

```
git add <file name>
```

or else if you want to stage all the changes then do

```
git add .
```

next step is to commit the staged changes to do that just write:-

```
git commit -m "<your commit message here>"
```

one shortcut method of staging all the files and commiting them is

```
git commit -am "<your commit message here>"
```

once you have commited the files just simply do

```
git push
```

Some additional commands that are useful:-

```
git branch --- to know the current branch you are on
git checkout <branchname>  --- to switch to some other branch
git checkout -b <branchname>  --- to create a new branch
git gc --prune=now  ---- to clear all the references
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Try to move/delete the `EyeGuideAuto_test/` folder which seems to be problematic.

Check if that folder has a nested `.git/` subdirectory in it.

Then check if the git add . works. If not, see if a git add of a few files does work (make a first commit), and proceed incrementally.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ? I am new to git. Please tell the the commands that I should use step by step.

Comment: @PratikPathare Just move the EyeGuideAuto_test folder out of the repo, outside, with a simple file explorer (so, not related to Git itself). See if adding the files works better *without* that folder.

Comment: I am unable to locate that folder on my system. Where exactly is that located?

Comment: just below MavenTest, where you are

Comment: I deleted that file. Then I typed git add . command. Nothing got added. I checked git status it is saying 'On branch origin nothing to commit, working tree clean'

Comment: @PratikPathare What does `git log` returns? And `git show`? (done in the `Maven_test` folder): do you see your existing files there?

Answer (score 0):

1. Move into the EyeGuideAuto_test/ directory.
2. Set the Folders Options to see hidden Files and Folders.
3. Delete the .git subdirectory.
4. Try the git add . again!